# Tcolorbox + minted source code listing that works in beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, incompatibility, minted

I copied and modified the code snippet in the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173854/109700) to highlight `cpp` code:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    colback=bg,
    colframe=black!70,
    listing only,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
    left=5mm,enhanced,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
```

Then, I use it in a Beamer frame like this:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{cppcode}    
int main() {
    int x, y; 
}
\end{cppcode}

\end{frame}
```

However, only an empty box with a gray margin shows up, with no code in it.

I have the following beamer class and theme:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

How can I make a similar tcolorbox code listing show up in beamer? Ideally, I would also like it to be breakable across frames.

**Update:** the author suggested in a comment to change the name of `bg`. I changed it to `bgg`, and now the background is also (a lighter) gray, but the code still does not show up.

Comment: Be sure to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the name `bg` for the background color conflicts with `beamer`. Just name it to something else

```
\newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    colback=cppcodebg,
    colframe=black!70,
    listing only,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
    left=5mm,enhanced,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{cppcodebg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
```

[image]

Minimal example, to be run with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

or `minted` can not run `pygmentize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    colback=cppcodebg,
    colframe=black!70,
    listing only,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
    left=5mm,enhanced,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{cppcodebg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{cppcode}    
int main() {
    int x, y; 
}
\end{cppcode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure what I did, I didn't seem to change anything, just kept recompiling, it gave the result mentioned in my update before, but now I get, for the command: `pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "prezentare".tex` the error message `Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using the kpsewhich option without having PowerShell installed. \end{cppcode}`. If I use `\begin{minted}{cpp}`, it compiles fine...

Comment: The error is at the line `\end{cppcode}` in `prezentare.vrb`.

Comment: @IVlad Sorry, can't check with Windows